# How to build the vtk examples from Lorensen Github?

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk

I'm new to vtk, and I've succesfully built vtk 8.1.1 from source, using Cmake and Visual Studio 2017, with the default options and examples.

But, I can't understand how to build the examples from the [Lorensen github](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/).

In [this page](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Instructions/ForUsers/), there are instructions for Linux. I could follow it using Windows, but my Cmake configure settings doesn't have a `Module_VTKExamples`, and I don't know how to include it in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

Here is what my Cmake window looks like. As I understand it, the `Module_VTKExamples` bool sould be right after `Module_vtkDomainsMicroscopy`, right?

I've also searched the `CMakeLists.txt` and there are no mentions of example module, other than the examples that already come with the vtk source.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of CMake options there is a `BUILD_EXAMPLES` option. You can turn that on. Then you will see another option called `Module_WikiExamples` which you can turn on as well. To verify that you have seen all CMake options that contain the word `Examples`, in the GUI you can enter `Examples` in the Search field.